# Question posted under anonymous user

Tags: support

I posted a question, and it was attributed to a different user than myself. Could I please get this question transferred to my account?

[Lambda calculus interpreter in Haskell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/139752/lambda-calculus-interpreter-in-haskell)

(I used Ice Weasel, running on Debian for my browser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've contacted the community team, requesting the accounts to be merged.

Custom-flagging the post for moderator attention was the right thing to do.

Alternatively, you could have contacted a Community Manager (CM) directly using the *contact us* link at the bottom of any page.

Your accounts should be merged <s>in 6 to 8 weeks</s> shortly.